# After passing the address of an array into a function in MIPs, am I supposed to save the values of the array into a stack?

Tags: mips

I have to translate this C++ function into MIPS.

```
void updatePoint(int *arg)
    {
      int distance;

      distance = findDistance(arg[0],arg[1],0,-1);
      if ((distance < 1) && (arg[2] < 0))
        arg[2] = - arg[2];
      distance = findDistance(arg[0],arg[1],10,-1);
      if ((distance < 1) && (arg[2] > 0))
        arg[2] = - arg[2];
      distance = findDistance(arg[0],arg[1],-1,0);
      if ((distance < 1) && (arg[3] < 0))
        arg[3] = - arg[3];
      distance = findDistance(arg[0],arg[1],-1,10);
      if ((distance < 1) && (arg[3] > 0))
        arg[3] = - arg[3];
       arg[0] = arg[0] + arg[2];
      arg[1] = arg[1] + arg[3];
      return;
}
```

Here's the MIPS code leading up to the function call.

```
        .data
redData:    .word   0:4
greenData:      .word   0:4
prmpt1:  .asciiz "Enter x-coordinate for red particle (0 to 10):"
prmpt2:  .asciiz "Enter y-coordinate for red particle (0 to 10):"
prmpt3:  .asciiz "Enter x-coordinate for green particle (0 to 10):"
prmpt4:  .asciiz "Enter y-coordinate for green particle (0 to 10):"
prmpt5:  .asciiz "cycle "
prmpt6:  .asciiz "red particle (x,y,xVel,yVel): "
prmpt7:  .asciiz "green particle (x,y,xVel,yVel): "
prmpt8:  .asciiz "Collison: oops, end of simulation!\n"
space:   .asciiz " "
endl:    .asciiz "\n"

# i     $s0
# cycle $s1 = 0
# dist  $s2

.text

main:   li      $s1,0

la      $s3,redData     #  redData[2] = 1 ;
li      $s4,1
sw      $s4,8($s3)
sw      $s4,12($s3)     #  redData[3] = 1 ;
la      $s3,greenData   #  greenData[2] = -1 ;
li      $s4,-1
sw      $s4,8($s3)
sw      $s4,12($s3)     #  greenData[3] = -1 ;

la      $a0,prmpt1      #  cout << prmpt1 ;
li      $v0,4
syscall
la      $s3,redData
li      $v0,5           #  cin >> redData[0] ;
syscall
sw      $v0,($s3)
la      $a0,prmpt2      #  cout << prmpt2 ;
li      $v0,4
syscall
li      $v0,5           #  cin >> redData[1] ;
syscall
sw      $v0,4($s3)
la      $a0,prmpt3      #  cout << prmpt3 ;
li      $v0,4
syscall
la      $s3,greenData   #  cin >> greenData[0] ;
li      $v0,5
syscall
sw      $v0,($s3)
la      $a0,prmpt4      #  cout << prmpt4 ;
li      $v0,4
syscall
li      $v0,5           #  cin >> greenData[1] ;
syscall
sw      $v0,4($s3)

loop:                           #  do {
la      $a0,prmpt5      #    cout << "cycle " << cycle << endl ;
li      $v0,4
syscall
move    $a0,$s1
li      $v0,1
syscall
la      $a0,endl
li      $v0,4
syscall
la      $a0,prmpt6      #    cout << "red particle (x,y,xVel,yVel): "
li      $v0,4
syscall
la      $s3, redData
lw      $a0,($s3)       #       << redData[0]
li      $v0,1
syscall
la      $a0,space       #       << " "
li      $v0,4
syscall
lw      $a0,4($s3)      #       << redData[1]
li      $v0,1
syscall
la      $a0,space       #       << " "
li      $v0,4
syscall
lw      $a0,8($s3)      #       << redData[2]
li      $v0,1
syscall
la      $a0,space       #       << " "
li      $v0,4
syscall
lw      $a0,12($s3)     #       << redData[3]
li      $v0,1
syscall
la      $a0,endl        #       << endl ;
li      $v0,4
syscall
la      $a0,prmpt7      #    cout << "green particle (x,y,xVel,yVel): "
li      $v0,4
syscall
la      $s3, greenData
lw      $a0,($s3)       #       << greenData[0]
li      $v0,1
syscall
la      $a0,space       #       << " "
li      $v0,4
syscall
lw      $a0,4($s3)      #       << greenData[1]
li      $v0,1
syscall
la      $a0,space       #       << " "
li      $v0,4
syscall
lw      $a0,8($s3)      #       << greenData[2]
li      $v0,1
syscall
la      $a0,space       #       << " "
li      $v0,4
syscall
lw      $a0,12($s3)     #       << greenData[3]
li      $v0,1
syscall
la      $a0,endl        #       << endl ;
li      $v0,4
syscall
la      $a0,endl        #       << endl ;
li      $v0,4
syscall

la      $a0,redData     #    updatePoint(redData) ;
jal     updatePoint
```

For updatePoint, should I be storing the values of arg[0] - arg[2] onto the stack? For doing that, should I do

```
lw      $s0, 0($a0) 
lw      $s1, 4($a0)
lw      $s2, 8($a0)
lw      $s3, 12($a0)
addi    $sp, $sp, -20
lw      $s0, 0($sp) 
lw      $s1, 4($sp)
lw      $s2, 8($sp)
lw      $s3, 12($sp)
lw      $ra, 16($sp)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For updatePoint, should I be storing the values of arg[0] - arg[2] onto the stack?

No, `arg` is an *array*. It is passed by *reference* (i.e. the pointer/address of `arg` is in `$a0`). Upon return, the values in `arg` are *expected* to be modified by `updatePoint`. It *will* modify `arg[0]` and `arg[1]` (i.e. see the last two lines of `updatePoint`) and, conditionally, *may* modify `arg[2]` and `arg[3]` along the way.

At every step in `updatePoint`, it *must* use the *updated* values in `arg` and, upon return, the *caller* of `updatePoint` must receive back `arg` with the *modified* values.

Nothing in `updatePoint` will allow `arg` to be modified by `findDistance` because all arguments to `findDistance` are passed by *value*.

So, you need to preserve [the pointer value in] `$a0` to prevent `updatePoint` from losing this *pointer* value to `arg` when calls to `findDistance` are made.

You *could* save it in the stack frame for `updatePoint`, but you'd have to reload it after every call to `findDistance`. Better to save it in a *callee* preserved register (e.g. `$s0`), so that `findDistance` won't disturb it.

---

Here's a sample that does the first call to `findDistance`. It should be easy for you to fill in the others as well as the last two C++ lines. Note that *nothing* else needs to be preserved in `updatePoint` [that's a strong hint]. You can use as many other temp regs as you want.

```
# void
# updatePoint(int *arg)
# {
#     int distance;
#
#     distance = findDistance(arg[0], arg[1], 0, -1);
#     if ((distance < 1) && (arg[2] < 0))
#         arg[2] = -arg[2];
#
#     distance = findDistance(arg[0], arg[1], 10, -1);
#     if ((distance < 1) && (arg[2] > 0))
#         arg[2] = -arg[2];
#
#     distance = findDistance(arg[0], arg[1], -1, 0);
#     if ((distance < 1) && (arg[3] < 0))
#         arg[3] = -arg[3];
#
#     distance = findDistance(arg[0], arg[1], -1, 10);
#     if ((distance < 1) && (arg[3] > 0))
#         arg[3] = -arg[3];
#
#     arg[0] = arg[0] + arg[2];
#     arg[1] = arg[1] + arg[3];
# }
updatePoint:
    subu    $sp,$sp,8
    sw      $ra,4($sp)
    sw      $s0,0($sp)

    # NOTE: now that we've preserved $s0 of our caller, we are free to use it
    # for whatever we want -- we use it to preserve the address of 'arg'
    move    $s0,$a0                 # preserve address of 'arg'

    #     distance = findDistance(arg[0], arg[1], 0, -1);
    lw      $a0,0($s0)              # get arg[0]
    lw      $a1,4($s0)              # get arg[1]
    li      $a2,0                   # set 0
    li      $a3,-1                  # set -1
    jal     findDistance

    #     if ((distance < 1) && (arg[2] < 0))
    bge     $v0,1,noset1            # distance < 1? if no, fly
    lw      $v0,8($s0)              # get arg[2]
    bgez    $v0,noset1              # is arg[2] < 0? if no, fly

    #         arg[2] = -arg[2];
    neg     $v0,$v0                 # get -arg[2]
    sw      $v0,8($s0)              # set arg[2] = -arg[2]
noset1:

    # with adjusted parameters repeat the above for all three remaining calls

    # perform last two lines of function ...

    lw      $ra,4($sp)
    lw      $s0,0($sp)
    addu    $sp,$sp,8
    jr      $ra

findDistance:
```

Note that a called function only needs to preserve `$s0-$s7`, must leave `$sp` as it found it, and must preserve `$ra` so it can do a `jr $ra` to return.

For `$ra`, the function could save it in (e.g.) `$t3` and later do `jr $t3`. The caller does *not* care if `$ra` is preserved or not (i.e. do the `jr` with any reg you wish, the idiomatic one being `$ra`). Just make sure the function returns to the correct place.

In the above code, note that after a call to `findDistance`, the return value [in `$v0`] is tested. After that, the return value isn't needed and the code uses `$v0` as a temp (vs. (e.g.) `$t0`)).

Likewise, a called function can use the argument registers `$a0-$a3` for whatever it wishes (i.e. *they* could be used as temp regs during calculations)

---

Here's your c++ function recoded to what I call "simple C". It is much more of a direct translation to asm:

```
void
updatePoint(int *arg)
{
    int distance;

    distance = findDistance(arg[0], arg[1], 0, -1);
    if (distance >= 1)
        goto noset1;
    if (arg[2] >= 0)
        goto noset1;
    arg[2] = -arg[2];
noset1:

    distance = findDistance(arg[0], arg[1], 10, -1);
    if (distance >= 1)
        goto noset2;
    if (arg[2] <= 0)
        goto noset2;
    arg[2] = -arg[2];
noset2:

    distance = findDistance(arg[0], arg[1], -1, 0);
    if (distance >= 1)
        goto noset3;
    if (arg[3] >= 0)
        goto noset3;
    arg[3] = -arg[3];
noset3:

    distance = findDistance(arg[0], arg[1], -1, 10);
    if (distance >= 1)
        goto noset4;
    if (arg[3] <= 0)
        goto noset4;
    arg[3] = -arg[3];
noset4:

    arg[0] = arg[0] + arg[2];
    arg[1] = arg[1] + arg[3];
}
```